# Validação com data annotations ASP.NET MVC funciona mas não exibe mensagem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Boa noite! estou tendo um problema no meu projeto em que estou tentando validar com data annotations e está funcionando, só cadastra no banco se atender as validações, mas o problema é que as mensagens que eu coloquei para exibir junto do data annotations não funcionam e eu não tenho idéia do por que isso está acontecendo, já olhei em vários códigos e está identico mas o meu valida mas não exibe a mensagem. Alguém me ajuda por favor!

Comment: Você no controller, quando não aceita a validação, está retornando o mesmo model para a View, e colocando as tags do Razor para poder mostrar as mensagens de validação. As vezes pode ser o CSS também que pode não estar mostrando as tags.

Comment: Eu removi todo codigo css e testei e não funcionou. Já o meu controller se atende a validação eu retorno minha view(), e se não atende eu to retornando a index, mas não importa se eu troco não aparece as mensagens só valida

Comment: coloca o seu codigo ai da controller , model e view

Answer (score 1):

Consegui achar o problema, no @Html.ValidationSummary() eu coloquei @Html.ValidationSummary(true), tem que ficar só @Html.ValidationSummary(), obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ProjetoDeInovacao.ViewModels;
using ProjetoDeInovacao.Models;
using ProjetoDeInovacao.Classes;

namespace ProjetoDeInovacao.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

```
    CadastroBLL bll = new CadastroBLL();
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
    // instancia  e  manda  valores  para  variaveis 
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(Cadastro model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            ViewData["Nome"] = model.Nome;
            ViewData["Email"] = model.Email;
            ViewData["Senha"] = model.Senha;
            bll.cadastrar(model);
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Login");
        }

    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Amorelli - Home";
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Carrinho()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Amorelli - Carrinho";
        return View();
    }
}
```

}

Model:

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ProjetoDeInovacao.Models
{
    public class Cadastro
    {
        private string nome;
        [Required (ErrorMessage = "Obrigatório informar o nome")]
        public string Nome
        {
            get { return nome; }
            set { nome = value; }
        }
        private string email;
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obrigatório informar o E-mail")]
        [RegularExpression(".+\@.+\..+", ErrorMessage = "O E-mail informado não é válido")]
        public string Email
        {
            get { return email; }
            set { email = value; }
        }
        private string senha;
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obrigatório informar uma senha")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 8)]
        public string Senha
        {
            get { return senha; }
            set { senha = value; }
        }
    }
}

View:
@model ProjetoDeInovacao.Models.Cadastro
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Amorelli - Login";
}

```
/*PARA VALIDAÇÃO DOS HELPERS*/
.field-validation-error {
    color: #f00;
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    background-color: #fee;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #b94a48;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}
```

### Entre na sua conta

Mantenha-me conectado
                        
                        Login
                    
                
            
            
                OU

### Cadastre-se!

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home"))
                    {
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
                        
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Nome, new { id = "Nome", placeholder = "Nome Completo" })
                        
                        
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Email, new { id = "Email1", placeholder = "Email" })
                        
                        
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Senha, new { id = "Senha1", placeholder = "Senha", type = "password" })
                        
                        Cadastrar
                        
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Favor corrigir os erros abaixo:")
                    }

(form login ainda sendo criado)